# Count the number of dynamically generated pages

Tags: c#, windows, linq, count

This is probably an easy solution but I can't get my head around it.

I have pages that are dynamically generated, and I count the pages that need to be generated via a LINQ statement (e.g.): (THIS IS UPDATED CODE to show where the questionCount is called and set to _labelQuestionCount - this is a snippet from a larger method that dynamicaly generated all pages and set all controls in dynamic pages)

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    int questionsCount = (from q in db.vw_Custom_SelectQuestionnaireQuestions        
    select q.tbl_QuestionnaireQuestion_Description).Count();
    _labelQuestionCount = questionsCount.ToString();
}

    Label labelCount = new Label();
    labelCount.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    labelCount.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 290);
    labelCount.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 30);
    labelCount.Tag = _dataSetRadioButtons.Tables["tbl_QuestionnaireAnswer_Score"];
    labelCount.Text = String.Format("Question Count: {0}", _labelQuestionCount);
```

Here is the global var:

```
   string _labelQuestionCount;
```

The reason for this is, as I click through the dynamically created pages, I would like to "count" them so that in my "next button" event I will know the x page is my final page and I can navigate/do some other code.

Current code for next button is: (UPdated)

```
        void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        bool c = IsChecked(_form);

        if (c == true)
        {
            var w = Convert.ToInt32(_labelQuestionCount);
            _form.Dispose();
            w--;

            if (w == 0)
            {
                //go to another page or do something else
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must select at least one.");
        }
    }
```

As you can see I try and the the value from a global variable (e.g. `__labelQuestionCount`) and try and count it "down" until get to 0 and do something else.

But, because my pages are dynamically generated, I never get to 0.

This is probably the wrong way to go about this, so if anyone could suggest or help it would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
geoNeo

Comment: A friendly suggestion, don't use single-letter variables, and no need to test a boolean for true. I.e., if you write `bool formIsChecked = IsChecked(_form);    if(formIsChecked) { var labelCount = ...` it's more readable to yourself and others.

Comment: sorry abel its just a test application - but thank you for the suggestion will keep it in mind for future posts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to reassign the decreased value(w--) to global variable _labelQuestionCount inside next button click event. because if you click on next the _labelQuestionCount will be remain same for all click.

Comment: Hi Vetrivel please could you elaborate on assigning the decreased value - fanx :D

Answer (score 0):

I would think about assigning to a `Page` some `int PageID`, if there is no any already. 
And when you recover the colelction of pages from the base, you don't count the count of them but get `PageID` of the latest page available **now**.

On `button_click` you ask again for the last element in the colleciton **at the moment of click** (cause it may be was changed, new pages were added to colleciton), revoer its `PageID`, and check if the page you swicthing to has the same ID, if yes, do what you need to do.

Comment: Hi Tigran - thanks for the reply am trying to implement all suggestions as we type - fanx :D